# File encoding other than utf-8

Tags: encoding

There is a file that I have to use in iso-2022-jp encoding.
I tried

```
:e ++enc=iso-2022-jp
:w
```

in the hope of converting the fileencodings to "iso-2022-jp" permanantly.
But the next time I opened the file, vim responds to me

```
:se fenc?
fileencodings=utf-8
```

.

I have not written any curious things in my vimrc.
Why is this happening?

Comment: 1) `fenc` stands for "fileencoding", not "fileencodings" (`fencs`).  2) How do you expect Vim to remember `++enc=xxx` "next time"?

Answer (score 1):

Vim does not remember any settings. It starts afresh every time. It will read your initialization scripts (not just `~/.vimrc` but ALL `~/.vim/*` files) upon startup. If what you want isn't happening automatically, you'll need to do something to make it happen. I recommend using a filetype plugin.

Let's say your filetype is `taro-enc`. You should write a file: `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/taro-enc.vim` with your vimscript (`enc=iso-2022-jp`). Now open the file and manually set the filetype `:set filetype=taro-enc`. Now your single file plugin should be sourced!

Well, almost. Perhaps you need to enable this feature. Make sure this is in your vimrc: `:filetype plugin on`.

And ok 1 more issue - this is manual! If you want to automatically detect your file as of `filetype=taro-enc`, then you can use your [~/..vim/filetype.vim](https://github.com/AriSweedler/dotfiles/blob/main/.vim/filetype.vim) file. (Mine is linked).

---

Extra notes:

You can realistically put all of this stuff just inside your vimrc, but it's better to keep organized. Makes your code more semantic.

Btw, I recommend using full names of commands when communicating with people to avoid silly issues like `fenc` vs. `fencs` :)

Comment: Not quite all `~/.vim` files; that’s only one directory on the rtp. Really any plugin files, as well as ftdetect (if enabled) and some other things, and that’s for all directories on the rtp :)